# Python add previous dict value to current one

Tags: python

Lets say I have this list of tuples (that may be length n):

```
keysVals = [('one',10),('two',15),('three',20),('four',5)]
```

And then I can create a dictionary from this list:

```
for k,v in keysVals:
    d.setdefault(week,int())
    d[k]+=v
```

How could I add the previous dict values to the current ones, with an output like this?:

```
d = {'one':10, 'two':25, 'three':45, 'four': 50}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate) to get a running sum:

```
import itertools

keysVals = [('one', 10), ('two', 15), ('three', 20), ('four', 5)]
keys, vals = zip(*keysVals)
d = dict(zip(keys, itertools.accumulate(vals)))
print(d)
# {'one': 10, 'two': 25, 'three': 45, 'four': 50}
```

Answer (score 2):

This complete program shows one approach, workable in both Python 2 and 3:

```
keysVals = [('one',10),('two',15),('three',20),('four',5)]
d = {}

sum = 0
for keyVal in keysVals:
    sum += keyVal[1]
    d[keyVal[0]] = sum

print(d)
```

It basically runs through the list adding each value to a sum (initially zero) then using that sum to populate the relevant dictionary item. The output is, as expected:

```
{'one': 10, 'two': 25, 'three': 45, 'four': 50}
```